# Socket writes to program after it gets terminated (C)

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

hope you're all well.

My problem is that I have a Server that runs on Java and a client that runs on C. Sending data from Java to C is not a problem at all, that goes really well. But when I try to write from C to Java, the TCP-message doesn't gets there until I terminate the C program (Ctrl + C), then I can see the message in my Java program.

I've tried to fflush the stdout and stdin but that doesn't work either.

Here is my c code that should write to the Javaclient:

```
void *sendToGUI(struct SocketStruct *sockServer){
    char *msg = "Try to send to Java";
    int len, bytes_sent;
    len = strlen(msg);
    write(sockServer->javaSocket, msg, len);
}
```

This method is running in a thread, and the receiving one is also running in a thread. Although, as I said, that one is no problem to receive messages.

Anyone that has a good thought of what it can be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please write a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will help you isolate the problem and if it persists, you can ask here.

Comment: Google for `TCP_NODELAY`

Comment: You should keep and use the resulting count from `write` (or `send`)

Comment: I did try with the TCP_NODELAY, but would not work. And had a result int from write and send and they didn't have -1 as a result.

Comment: Any chance you can watch it happen with WireShark? It will let you know for sure which side the problem is on.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the Java code is reading lines, and you aren't sending lines. Add a line terminator to the message.

Comment: A hugh thank you! I looked at Wireshark and did see some communication between the programs. Problem was with Java (and thought all the time it was the C). Again, thank you!